# Is it possible to stop solr from caching facets in filterQueryCache

Tags: solr

I've been trying to tune my filterQueryCache by not caching filter queries that are essentially unique as they are distance queries using cache=false

This works for filter queries, but I then noticed the facets for distance are also getting cached.

Is it possible to stop the facets getting cached, I've tried passing in local params cache=false, with no effect.

My issue with the cache is in theory I should be able to cache all my searchable values, but upon analysing the cache I can see all the factet distance queries too and as these are unique, it causes evictions. Some stats over the last 12 hours:

cumulative_lookups: 34036761
cumulative_hits: 21513257
cumulative_hitratio: 0.63
cumulative_inserts: 12526368
cumulative_evictions: 11884925

Comment: If you have faceting on the distance field, it will still add to the filter query cache. so maybe you have a facet query on the distance field that is adding to the cache.

Comment: I know the facets are getting added to the query cache, I'm trying to stop them by telling them not to cache.